# Memory leak (?) when converting from string to integer in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, realloc

so i wrote this program which reads two lines of text from a text file called "input.txt" (it has two lines, a number on each) then convert both numbers to integers in two different arrays. for integer arrays i used malloc and realloc to dynamically allocate memory. as you can see in the picture below it works fine for second number, but the first number is just some random numbers (changes each time). why is this happening?

(I'm using codeblocks.)

[image]

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#define SIZE_MAX 10
#define SIZE_USE (SIZE_MAX-1)

int input(char num_first[], char num_second[]);
int convert(int iinum_first[], int iinum_second[], char num_first[], char num_second[], int firstlen, int secondlen, int c, int c2);

int main()
{

    char num_first[SIZE_MAX]; // original input as string
    char num_second[SIZE_MAX];

    input(num_first, num_second);

    int firstlen = strlen(num_first)-1;
    int secondlen = strlen(num_second);

    int i, c=0, c2=0;
    for (i = 0; i <= firstlen; i++)
    {
        c++; // counts number of elements needed to resize array
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= secondlen; i++)
    {
        c2++;
    }

    int *iinum_first = NULL; // converted integer input
    int *iinum_second = NULL;

    iinum_first = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    iinum_second = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));


    convert(iinum_first, iinum_second, num_first, num_second, firstlen, secondlen, c, c2);

    printf("first integer: ");
    for (i = 0; i < firstlen; i++) // print first integer
    {
        printf("%d", iinum_first[i]);
    }
    printf("\nsecond integer: ");
    for (i = 0; i < secondlen; i++) // print second integer
    {
        printf("%d", iinum_second[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    return 0;
}

int input(char num_first[], char num_second[])
{
    FILE *fPTR;
    int i;

    if ((fPTR = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        puts(":( File could not be opened.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (fgets(num_first, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL)
            printf("first string: "); // print string input
        puts(num_first);
        if (fgets(num_second, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL)
            printf("second string: ");
        puts(num_second);
        fclose(fPTR);
    }

    return 0;
}

int convert(int iinum_first[], int iinum_second[], char num_first[], char num_second[], int firstlen, int secondlen, int c, int c2)
{
    // dynamic memory allocation

    int i;

    int *temp = NULL;
    int *temp2 = NULL;

    temp = (int*)realloc(iinum_first, c * sizeof(int));
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        iinum_first = temp; // moving temporary data to main array
    }
    else
    {
        free(iinum_first);
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
        return 1;
    }


    temp2 = (int*)realloc(iinum_second, c2 * sizeof(int));
    if (temp2 != NULL)
    {
        iinum_second = temp2; // moving temporary data to main array
    }
    else
    {
        free(iinum_second);
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; num_first[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        switch (num_first[i])
        {
        case 48:
            iinum_first[i] = 0;
            break;
        case 49:
            iinum_first[i] = 1;
            break;
        case 50:
            iinum_first[i] = 2;
            break;
        case 51:
            iinum_first[i] = 3;
            break;
        case 52:
            iinum_first[i] = 4;
            break;
        case 53:
            iinum_first[i] = 5;
            break;
        case 54:
            iinum_first[i] = 6;
            break;
        case 55:
            iinum_first[i] = 7;
            break;
        case 56:
            iinum_first[i] = 8;
            break;
        case 57:
            iinum_first[i] = 9;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; num_second[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        switch (num_second[i])
        {
        case 48:
            iinum_second[i] = 0;
            break;
        case 49:
            iinum_second[i] = 1;
            break;
        case 50:
            iinum_second[i] = 2;
            break;
        case 51:
            iinum_second[i] = 3;
            break;
        case 52:
            iinum_second[i] = 4;
            break;
        case 53:
            iinum_second[i] = 5;
            break;
        case 54:
            iinum_second[i] = 6;
            break;
        case 55:
            iinum_second[i] = 7;
            break;
        case 56:
            iinum_second[i] = 8;
            break;
        case 57:
            iinum_second[i] = 9;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh my.. these switches are killing me. Why not just `iinum_first[i] = num_first[i] - 48 ` ??

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Good point.

Comment: BTW `SIZE_MAX` already use by C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY. but it's working fine so far.

Comment: @vvvsg It will eventually stop doing so, if expanded with something that want to use the original `SIZE_MAX`...

Comment: @vvvsg No relationship with it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. i had to use realloc in main before i call convert function.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#define SIZE_MAX 10
#define SIZE_USE (SIZE_MAX-1)

int input(char num_first[], char num_second[]);
int convert(int iinum_first[], int iinum_second[], char num_first[], char num_second[], int firstlen, int secondlen, int c, int c2);

int main()
{

    char num_first[SIZE_MAX]; // original input as string
    char num_second[SIZE_MAX];

    input(num_first, num_second);

    int firstlen = strlen(num_first)-1;
    int secondlen = strlen(num_second);

    int i, c=0, c2=0;
    for (i = 0; i <= firstlen; i++)
    {
        c++; // counts number of elements needed to resize array
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= secondlen; i++)
    {
        c2++;
    }

    int *iinum_first = NULL; // converted integer input
    int *iinum_second = NULL;

    iinum_first = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    iinum_second = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    int *temp = NULL;
    int *temp2 = NULL;

    temp = (int*)realloc(iinum_first, c * sizeof(int));
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        iinum_first = temp; // moving temporary data to main array
    }
    else
    {
        free(iinum_first);
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
        return 1;
    }


    temp2 = (int*)realloc(iinum_second, c2 * sizeof(int));
    if (temp2 != NULL)
    {
        iinum_second = temp2; // moving temporary data to main array
    }
    else
    {
        free(iinum_second);
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    convert(iinum_first, iinum_second, num_first, num_second, firstlen, secondlen, c, c2);

    printf("first integer: ");
    for (i = 0; i < firstlen; i++) // print first integer
    {
        printf("%d", iinum_first[i]);
    }
    printf("\nsecond integer: ");
    for (i = 0; i < secondlen; i++) // print second integer
    {
        printf("%d", iinum_second[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    return 0;
}

int input(char num_first[], char num_second[])
{
    FILE *fPTR;
    int i;

    if ((fPTR = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        puts(":( File could not be opened.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (fgets(num_first, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL)
            printf("first string: "); // print string input
        puts(num_first);
        if (fgets(num_second, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL)
            printf("second string: ");
        puts(num_second);
        fclose(fPTR);
    }

    return 0;
}

int convert(int iinum_first[], int iinum_second[], char num_first[], char num_second[], int firstlen, int secondlen, int c, int c2)
{
    // dynamic memory allocation
    int i;

    for (i = 0; num_first[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        switch (num_first[i])
        {
        case 48:
            iinum_first[i] = 0;
            break;
        case 49:
            iinum_first[i] = 1;
            break;
        case 50:
            iinum_first[i] = 2;
            break;
        case 51:
            iinum_first[i] = 3;
            break;
        case 52:
            iinum_first[i] = 4;
            break;
        case 53:
            iinum_first[i] = 5;
            break;
        case 54:
            iinum_first[i] = 6;
            break;
        case 55:
            iinum_first[i] = 7;
            break;
        case 56:
            iinum_first[i] = 8;
            break;
        case 57:
            iinum_first[i] = 9;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; num_second[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        switch (num_second[i])
        {
        case 48:
            iinum_second[i] = 0;
            break;
        case 49:
            iinum_second[i] = 1;
            break;
        case 50:
            iinum_second[i] = 2;
            break;
        case 51:
            iinum_second[i] = 3;
            break;
        case 52:
            iinum_second[i] = 4;
            break;
        case 53:
            iinum_second[i] = 5;
            break;
        case 54:
            iinum_second[i] = 6;
            break;
        case 55:
            iinum_second[i] = 7;
            break;
        case 56:
            iinum_second[i] = 8;
            break;
        case 57:
            iinum_second[i] = 9;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the program using atoi instead of creating a new weel, but I see the only difference in

`int firstlen = strlen(num_first)-1;` 
instead of

`int firstlen = strlen(num_first);`

Comment: btw from what I know, atoi returns an integer, but i want each digit in an array element.

Comment: Ok, I then prefer a loop,like
`int a = atoi(str);
int n = log10(a)+1;
int array[n];
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    array[n-i]=a%10;
    a /=10;
}`